# Boot Problems in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2, lightdm

I have several problems when booting into mate under Ubuntu 22.04

1. The boot starts both the console and tty1. Makes logging on in text mode nearly impossible
2. The graphical boot starts lightdm twice
3. The terminal resolution in lightdm is too small.
4. Logging on in text mode to root results in no display of typed input.  It is not clear if this input is received.

Any help would be appreciated

Below is /etc/default/grub.

If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.
For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax noresume noveau.modset=0 splash quiet"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5

#Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs

#This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)

#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)

#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

#The resolution used on graphical terminal
note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE. you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

#Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

#Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

#Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

Comment: please edit your question and remove the yelling,we are addults here and do not yell to each other.